# Unity 4.6.6 iOS Build Issue

Tags: unity, ios, xcode

I am using unity 4.6.6 to create a Xcode build. When I create a build I am getting following error

Cannot initialize return object of type 'Singleton_1_t6738 *' with an rvalue of type 'Singleton_1_t6737 *'

[image: Screenshot showing issue]

Answer (score -1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton

Hope these links help.

Have you consulted the Unity website?